# Perfect in power

Tags: c, algorithm

I got tasked in a course to write a function that will calculate "perfect in power" numbers for example this one.

```
153 = 1^3+5^3+3^3
```

So far, I have tried the code below.

```
int CheckIfPrefectInPower(int n)
{
    int i, sum=0, userInput;

    // Deals with the Power exponent
    for  (i = 0; sum<n; i++) 
    {
        userInput = n;
        sum = 0;
        while(userInput>0)//the loop calculate the sum
        {
            sum += pow((double)(userInput % 10), (double)i);
            userInput = userInput / 10;
        }

        if (sum == n)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a better and  simpler way to calculate it?
2. How to deal with a number like `1111` or `1000`?

Comment: Doesnt look like that function copes  where n <= 0

Comment: I think it is, cause then the sum will 0 and then in perfect as wall at least by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with your first question. Your code **linearly** tries to find out an exponent `i` so that the sum of all `d^i` is equal to n, where `d` represents a digit of the number `n` you're given. So, for a case where the exponent value you're looking for is `E`, your algorithm will have to iterate `E` times, causing you to have a time complexity of `O(E * log(n))`. (i.e. `log` factor is added due to the inner while loop)

One could think that a binary search approach would lead to a faster solution, due to its logarithmic time complexity. However, it turns out that binary search does not give you a much better solution in this case.

Let's assume that the number `n` is smaller than or equal to the largest 32-bit signed integer value. Then, in the worst case (e.g. for `n = 2^31 - 1`) it would hold that `k < 31`. Even if the integer was a 64-bit unsigned integer, then you can figure out that `k < 64` holds true.

So, even though the time complexity of binary search is *superior* to that of your linear search approach, in practice, your algorithm is not too inefficient, mostly due to the search space being too small. (i.e. `0 <= k < 31` for 32-bit signed integer) In other words, so long as you use basic data type for n, the `E` factor I mentioned in the initial time complexity of your algorithm is relatively small enough to be considered as a constant factor.

Your second question seems to ask how to handle the cases where multiple exponent values are correct. Well, does it really matter which one you choose? The function you coded just seems to find out whether the number is *perfect in power* or not. So, which exponent(s) fulfill that condition is not that relevant. If the relevant exponent is to be returned, then it is a question for your instructors to clarify which exponent to return. (e.g. the smallest, the largest, etc.)

Comment: Firstly Thank you for the answer! The second question is about how to get out from the for loop cause now it will stuck in the loop for numbers like 1111 cause the sum of the digits for any expo will always be less then 1111.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer, since `i < 31` will always hold true in your case, you don't need to iterate for `i` values that are greater than 30. You can just change the termination condition of the outer loop with `i < 31` and it would work.

Comment: To have a more portable code, you can instead use the following condition: `i < 8 * sizeof(n) - 1`.

Comment: This is what I wanted 
Thanks!